# Convert dates from monthly to quarterly?

Tags: r, datetime

I have my data frame of the format

```
   CALENDAR_MONTH_BEGIN_DT MEASURE_VALUE
1                2023-03-01     122306539
2                2022-12-01     102989175
3                2022-09-01      88522782
```

where `CALENDAT_MONTH_BEGIN_DT` is of date class

Whats the best way to convert the dates to format 2023-Q1 or 2023-Q2